# How to set "Changes" and "Started by" from Jenkins API?

Tags: api, jenkins

As part of our build process we have several jobs that are invoked via the jenkins web api, using urls of the form:

```
http://jenkins.host:8080/job/<jobname>/build
```

When looking at a build job, there are two pieces of information right under the title: `Changes` and `Started by`.  I want to know how to set them when using the above API

I have looked all over the web, at https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API and http://jenkins.host:8080/job/[jobname]/api but nowhere can I find any information on how to set those two fields.

We have the transmission of parameters working just fine, they're being used to fine tune what the build does, I just can't find anything about setting those two fields.

Comment: I don't think those are meant to be set by user. Changes are fetched for version control and started by is the logged in user.

Comment: That's not good.  In that case, I'd have expected the "pseudo-user" who provides the credentials when invoking the url to show (which is bad), but it's actually showing as `remote host 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`.  I really don't want to do this by polling, it's trivial to set this up to use the API, but it'll be a spectacular pain to have Jenkins poll the other system..  The reason that user is bad, is that I have available the user that started the process on the other system, and can send that down.  That's obviously the correct name to use, not the user invoking the API.